# Building code for counting the number of decimal places in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I am now trying to build a source code for counting the number of decimal places of floating point value input by the user.

Below is my code written in Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

class CountDecimalPlaces{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double double1 = input.nextDouble();
        int int1 = (int) double1;
        String string1 = Double.toString(double1), string2 = Integer.toString(int1);
        int string2Size = string2.length() + 1, string1Size = string1.length() - string2Size;

        System.out.println("Here we know that the number of  decimal places that you input is " + string1Size);
    }
}
```

And it results in the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2569)
        at CountDecimalPlaces.main(CountDecimalPlaces.java:8)
```

Note that this error message occurs after I enter a floating-point input, not when I am trying to run the source code.
What's wrong?

Comment: this works for me. "InputMismatchException" means there's sth wrong with your input.

Comment: My input was 7.72384294

Comment: 7.72384294
Here we know that the number of  decimal places that you input is 8

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but why not just accept a string, search for `'.'`, and count the number of characters after that character?

Comment: @CryptoFool any way to do that? I'm a new learner. Somebody says we can't count the number of floating-point in Java. So, I change the double to string only to count the number of it behind the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple cause for your problem, but, your code as written is more fundamentally just entirely broken.

### The immediate problem

A Scanner has a **locale** - a configuration about the ways things are entered in the language/country that you configured in your OS. Your OS is configured to use a comma and not a dot. Either call `scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)` to change this locale, or, enter numbers with commas instead.

### But.. nevermind. This code does not work and never will

`double` doesn't store numbers the way you think it does. For example, 0.3? That's not a double. It simply isn't. Computers aren't magical; there are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, and double can represent a lot more than just a number between 0 and 1. Computers aren't magical; they don't have infinite room to store this stuff. It can't even store 0.3. Computers are binary, too. They use binary counting, not decimal counting, so the question 'how many digits does it have' (which implies: "... in decimal") is entirely foreign to a computer, which counts in binary and not decimal.

`BigDecimal` is a class that can do it. I highly doubt this homework involves having to do that. Point is, for many, many numbers, this code will not work and nothing can be done to make it work, other than to get rid of almost all of it, and use `BigDecimal` instead, which is well beyond the level of this homework.

I think the only valid conclusion is that whatever you got this exercise from, it's undoable.

Comment: It is doable.  You just need to treat this as a question about the *string representation* provided by the user.   (The point that rzwitserloot is making I think is that there is an important distinction between numbers and representations of numbers.   This is a rather deep distinction.  It is fundamentally the same distinction that the famous Magritte "Ceci n'est pas un pipe" painting is making.)

Comment: A key question then is whether e.g. `,0000` requires an answer of 4, or 5, or 0, or 1. You're more or less handrolling parts of `BigDecimal`, but, touché, that's possibly the intent of this homework and borderline doable at this level. I still thoroughly dislike this exercise, for the little that's worth.